# Negation of the statement - ' There exists at least $4$ vertices each of degree at most $5$ '

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

' There exists at least $4$ vertices, each of degree at most $5$ ' .
What is the negation of this statement??

My answers : Given any set of vertices, at most three of them has degree at most $5$

Given any set of vertices $S$ , any subset of $S$ with cardinality $4$ , contains a vertex of degree $\geq6$.

I think both of them are equivalent and both are negation of the statement.  Am I correct? Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Why not a simple "There _does not exist_ at least 4 vertices each of degree at most 5"?

Comment: That is true but I'm wondering if other two are correct?

Comment: Carnality is not the same as cardinality :-)

Comment: Sorry TonyK, that's typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are both correct but the second one involves invoking a somewhat nontrivial fact: if every subset of size $4$ fails the condition, then every subset of size greater than or equal to $4$ fails the condition. The truth value is equivalent but I wouldn't say that they are identical statements.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement can really be thought of as:

'Given any $4$ vertices, at least one will have a degree $\geq 6$'

And yes, the two are then easily seen to be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks man   , this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I find symbolic manipulation helpful for negating complex statements. I’d write this as

$\neg\big(\exists \{v_1\dots v_n|n\geq4\}$ s.t. $\forall i\leq n$, deg$(v_i)\leq5\big)$

and we can negate by reversing symbols:

$\forall \{v_1\dots v_n|n\geq4\}, \exists i\leq n$ s.t. deg$(v_i)>5$.

I’d render the English version as “every collection of at least 4 vertices has a vertex of degree more than 5.”

---

What I'm doing here is using the following rule from symbolic logic:

*Let* P(x) *be any logical statement which depends on* x, *and* x *takes on values from* S. *Then*
$$\neg\big(\forall x\in S, P(x)\big) \iff \exists x\in S \text{ s.t. } \neg P(x)$$ 
*and* 
$$\neg\big(\exists x\in S \text{ s.t. } P(x)\big) \iff \forall x\in S, \neg P(x).$$

This means we can negate chained together statements as follows (I'm abusing the notation here, but hopefully my meaning is clear).
$$\neg\big(\forall \sim, \exists\sim, \forall \sim P(x)\big)\iff \exists\sim, \forall \sim, \exists\sim \neg P(x)$$

Comment: I just noticed you tagged this as precalculus, so you might not have seen these before. Upside-down A means “for all”, backwards E means “there exists”.

Comment: I know these symbols from my childhood  :)

Comment: I think negation doesn't work the way of just inter changing for all and there exists. Suppose if I have 5 vectors one of which has degree 6 but all other 4 has degree 3 , then?

Comment: There is a bit more to it, that's true. I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: By the way, if you have 5 vectors one of which has degree 6, then you do have a collection of at least 4 vectors, and it does have a vertex of degree more than 5.

Comment: although writing as symbols certainly helps  just changing for all and there exists  is not correct

Comment: If you read carefully, you'll see that the final statement (the P(x) part) is also negated. If you'd like some long form explanation on how this works, check out this pdf: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/Math300Winter2011/m300Quantifiers.pdf